# How can I extract clear peaks from auto-correlated data in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, autocorrelation

I want to extract the clear peaks of the ACF of a given time series.

```
def computeACF(Y):
    yAC = np.correlate(Y-np.mean(Y), Y-np.mean(Y), mode='full')
    ACF = yAC/np.max(yAC)
    x= np.arange(0,len(ACF))-(len(ACF)-1)/2
    return ACF,x
```

I have a time series, where I apply a smoothing window before calculating ACF.

```
ts = df[col].rolling(round(df.shape[0]*0.01)).mean()

acf,x = computeACF(ts)
```

Based on the acf, I want to find the clear peaks, which are marked with red in the plot

[image]

But when I use functions such as `find_peaks` from `scipy.signal` package, I find too many noisy peaks.

```
peak_idx = find_peaks(acf)[0]
plt.plot(x,acf)
plt.scatter(x[peak_idx],acf[peak_idx],c='r')
```

[image]

And if I look at the median absolute deviation of the data points I find more points than just the peaks.

```
 acf_median = np.median(acf)
 acf_mad = median_abs_deviation(acf)  
 threshold_acf = acf_median + acf_mad *2

 plt.plot(x,acf)
 plt.scatter(x[acf > threshold_acf],acf[acf > threshold_acf],c='r')
```

[image]

So what would be a good way of detecting the clear peaks from ACF in Python? Would it be to tune the parameters of `find_peaks` function, or are there any other more robust methods to use?

Appreciate any tips.

EDIT : Here is the ACF data if anyone would want to try it out.

```
x = [-475.0, -474.0, -473.0, -472.0, -471.0, -470.0, -469.0, -468.0, -467.0, -466.0, -465.0, -464.0, -463.0, -462.0, -461.0, -460.0, -459.0, -458.0, -457.0, -456.0, -455.0, -454.0, -453.0, -452.0, -451.0, -450.0, -449.0, -448.0, -447.0, -446.0, -445.0, -444.0, -443.0, -442.0, -441.0, -440.0, -439.0, -438.0, -437.0, -436.0, -435.0, -434.0, -433.0, -432.0, -431.0, -430.0, -429.0, -428.0, -427.0, -426.0, -425.0, -424.0, -423.0, -422.0, -421.0, -420.0, -419.0, -418.0, -417.0, -416.0, -415.0, -414.0, -413.0, -412.0, -411.0, -410.0, -409.0, -408.0, -407.0, -406.0, -405.0, -404.0, -403.0, -402.0, -401.0, -400.0, -399.0, -398.0, -397.0, -396.0, -395.0, -394.0, -393.0, -392.0, -391.0, -390.0, -389.0, -388.0, -387.0, -386.0, -385.0, -384.0, -383.0, -382.0, -381.0, -380.0, -379.0, -378.0, -377.0, -376.0, -375.0, -374.0, -373.0, -372.0, -371.0, -370.0, -369.0, -368.0, -367.0, -366.0, -365.0, -364.0, -363.0, -362.0, -361.0, -360.0, -359.0, -358.0, -357.0, -356.0, -355.0, -354.0, -353.0, -352.0, -351.0, -350.0, -349.0, -348.0, -347.0, -346.0, -345.0, -344.0, -343.0, -342.0, -341.0, -340.0, -339.0, -338.0, -337.0, -336.0, -335.0, -334.0, -333.0, -332.0, -331.0, -330.0, -329.0, -328.0, -327.0, -326.0, -325.0, -324.0, -323.0, -322.0, -321.0, -320.0, -319.0, -318.0, -317.0, -316.0, -315.0, -314.0, -313.0, -312.0, -311.0, -310.0, -309.0, -308.0, -307.0, -306.0, -305.0, -304.0, -303.0, -302.0, -301.0, -300.0, -299.0, -298.0, -297.0, -296.0, -295.0, -294.0, -293.0, -292.0, -291.0, -290.0, -289.0, -288.0, -287.0, -286.0, -285.0, -284.0, -283.0, -282.0, -281.0, -280.0, -279.0, -278.0, -277.0, -276.0, -275.0, -274.0, -273.0, -272.0, -271.0, -270.0, -269.0, -268.0, -267.0, -266.0, -265.0, -264.0, -263.0, -262.0, -261.0, -260.0, -259.0, -258.0, -257.0, -256.0, -255.0, -254.0, -253.0, -252.0, -251.0, -250.0, -249.0, -248.0, -247.0, -246.0, -245.0, -244.0, -243.0, -242.0, -241.0, -240.0, -239.0, -238.0, -237.0, -236.0, -235.0, -234.0, -233.0, -232.0, -231.0, -230.0, -229.0, -228.0, -227.0, -226.0, -225.0, -224.0, -223.0, -222.0, -221.0, -220.0, -219.0, -218.0, -217.0, -216.0, -215.0, -214.0, -213.0, -212.0, -211.0, -210.0, -209.0, -208.0, -207.0, -206.0, -205.0, -204.0, -203.0, -202.0, -201.0, -200.0, -199.0, -198.0, -197.0, -196.0, -195.0, -194.0, -193.0, -192.0, -191.0, -190.0, -189.0, -188.0, -187.0, -186.0, -185.0, -184.0, -183.0, -182.0, -181.0, -180.0, -179.0, -178.0, -177.0, -176.0, -175.0, -174.0, -173.0, -172.0, -171.0, -170.0, -169.0, -168.0, -167.0, -166.0, -165.0, -164.0, -163.0, -162.0, -161.0, -160.0, -159.0, -158.0, -157.0, -156.0, -155.0, -154.0, -153.0, -152.0, -151.0, -150.0, -149.0, -148.0, -147.0, -146.0, -145.0, -144.0, -143.0, -142.0, -141.0, -140.0, -139.0, -138.0, -137.0, -136.0, -135.0, -134.0, -133.0, -132.0, -131.0, -130.0, -129.0, -128.0, -127.0, -126.0, -125.0, -124.0, -123.0, -122.0, -121.0, -120.0, -119.0, -118.0, -117.0, -116.0, -115.0, -114.0, -113.0, -112.0, -111.0, -110.0, -109.0, -108.0, -107.0, -106.0, -105.0, -104.0, -103.0, -102.0, -101.0, -100.0, -99.0, -98.0, -97.0, -96.0, -95.0, -94.0, -93.0, -92.0, -91.0, -90.0, -89.0, -88.0, -87.0, -86.0, -85.0, -84.0, -83.0, -82.0, -81.0, -80.0, -79.0, -78.0, -77.0, -76.0, -75.0, -74.0, -73.0, -72.0, -71.0, -70.0, -69.0, -68.0, -67.0, -66.0, -65.0, -64.0, -63.0, -62.0, -61.0, -60.0, -59.0, -58.0, -57.0, -56.0, -55.0, -54.0, -53.0, -52.0, -51.0, -50.0, -49.0, -48.0, -47.0, -46.0, -45.0, -44.0, -43.0, -42.0, -41.0, -40.0, -39.0, -38.0, -37.0, -36.0, -35.0, -34.0, -33.0, -32.0, -31.0, -30.0, -29.0, -28.0, -27.0, -26.0, -25.0, -24.0, -23.0, -22.0, -21.0, -20.0, -19.0, -18.0, -17.0, -16.0, -15.0, -14.0, -13.0, -12.0, -11.0, -10.0, -9.0, -8.0, -7.0, -6.0, -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0, 81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0, 89.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0, 94.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0, 99.0, 100.0, 101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, 107.0, 108.0, 109.0, 110.0, 111.0, 112.0, 113.0, 114.0, 115.0, 116.0, 117.0, 118.0, 119.0, 120.0, 121.0, 122.0, 123.0, 124.0, 125.0, 126.0, 127.0, 128.0, 129.0, 130.0, 131.0, 132.0, 133.0, 134.0, 135.0, 136.0, 137.0, 138.0, 139.0, 140.0, 141.0, 142.0, 143.0, 144.0, 145.0, 146.0, 147.0, 148.0, 149.0, 150.0, 151.0, 152.0, 153.0, 154.0, 155.0, 156.0, 157.0, 158.0, 159.0, 160.0, 161.0, 162.0, 163.0, 164.0, 165.0, 166.0, 167.0, 168.0, 169.0, 170.0, 171.0, 172.0, 173.0, 174.0, 175.0, 176.0, 177.0, 178.0, 179.0, 180.0, 181.0, 182.0, 183.0, 184.0, 185.0, 186.0, 187.0, 188.0, 189.0, 190.0, 191.0, 192.0, 193.0, 194.0, 195.0, 196.0, 197.0, 198.0, 199.0, 200.0, 201.0, 202.0, 203.0, 204.0, 205.0, 206.0, 207.0, 208.0, 209.0, 210.0, 211.0, 212.0, 213.0, 214.0, 215.0, 216.0, 217.0, 218.0, 219.0, 220.0, 221.0, 222.0, 223.0, 224.0, 225.0, 226.0, 227.0, 228.0, 229.0, 230.0, 231.0, 232.0, 233.0, 234.0, 235.0, 236.0, 237.0, 238.0, 239.0, 240.0, 241.0, 242.0, 243.0, 244.0, 245.0, 246.0, 247.0, 248.0, 249.0, 250.0, 251.0, 252.0, 253.0, 254.0, 255.0, 256.0, 257.0, 258.0, 259.0, 260.0, 261.0, 262.0, 263.0, 264.0, 265.0, 266.0, 267.0, 268.0, 269.0, 270.0, 271.0, 272.0, 273.0, 274.0, 275.0, 276.0, 277.0, 278.0, 279.0, 280.0, 281.0, 282.0, 283.0, 284.0, 285.0, 286.0, 287.0, 288.0, 289.0, 290.0, 291.0, 292.0, 293.0, 294.0, 295.0, 296.0, 297.0, 298.0, 299.0, 300.0, 301.0, 302.0, 303.0, 304.0, 305.0, 306.0, 307.0, 308.0, 309.0, 310.0, 311.0, 312.0, 313.0, 314.0, 315.0, 316.0, 317.0, 318.0, 319.0, 320.0, 321.0, 322.0, 323.0, 324.0, 325.0, 326.0, 327.0, 328.0, 329.0, 330.0, 331.0, 332.0, 333.0, 334.0, 335.0, 336.0, 337.0, 338.0, 339.0, 340.0, 341.0, 342.0, 343.0, 344.0, 345.0, 346.0, 347.0, 348.0, 349.0, 350.0, 351.0, 352.0, 353.0, 354.0, 355.0, 356.0, 357.0, 358.0, 359.0, 360.0, 361.0, 362.0, 363.0, 364.0, 365.0, 366.0, 367.0, 368.0, 369.0, 370.0, 371.0, 372.0, 373.0, 374.0, 375.0, 376.0, 377.0, 378.0, 379.0, 380.0, 381.0, 382.0, 383.0, 384.0, 385.0, 386.0, 387.0, 388.0, 389.0, 390.0, 391.0, 392.0, 393.0, 394.0, 395.0, 396.0, 397.0, 398.0, 399.0, 400.0, 401.0, 402.0, 403.0, 404.0, 405.0, 406.0, 407.0, 408.0, 409.0, 410.0, 411.0, 412.0, 413.0, 414.0, 415.0, 416.0, 417.0, 418.0, 419.0, 420.0, 421.0, 422.0, 423.0, 424.0, 425.0, 426.0, 427.0, 428.0, 429.0, 430.0, 431.0, 432.0, 433.0, 434.0, 435.0, 436.0, 437.0, 438.0, 439.0, 440.0, 441.0, 442.0, 443.0, 444.0, 445.0, 446.0, 447.0, 448.0, 449.0, 450.0, 451.0, 452.0, 453.0, 454.0, 455.0, 456.0, 457.0, 458.0, 459.0, 460.0, 461.0, 462.0, 463.0, 464.0, 465.0, 466.0, 467.0, 468.0, 469.0, 470.0, 471.0, 472.0, 473.0, 474.0, 475.0]

acf = [0.001229682097571425, 0.0019425176799605125, 0.001975580296023691, 0.000349485732444141, -0.001426414454630863, -0.004548739746709569, -0.007657944211140158, -0.012304567393469645, -0.01551109417080322, -0.018732567282240306, -0.019386579658324597, -0.01948438303628221, -0.01711022248533462, -0.014043168140413015, -0.010094051895077578, -0.007083131873659212, -0.0037594797776018263, -0.0002579548962973546, 0.0035431812319980213, 0.007984727843674957, 0.011707139006081635, 0.015414603834384803, 0.019054639017992002, 0.024582361970626083, 0.02898272059290328, 0.034360637922041894, 0.03910179578070975, 0.04389726245642545, 0.04540613294751811, 0.04656108337457199, 0.04558486910911133, 0.04482589011184211, 0.04317172838651094, 0.042073775659306444, 0.04047392275102313, 0.03998648783899319, 0.0390365152288288, 0.03677947999660502, 0.033666624519263645, 0.030947051588905383, 0.02957390376355084, 0.02757529178891822, 0.028498060613677174, 0.030344079328249705, 0.03483810925051911, 0.03976660970917137, 0.04538800396179765, 0.0488782335219094, 0.05312878652069113, 0.055111490031110995, 0.056727152649843966, 0.05857499687087188, 0.061741199035151864, 0.0637275535584825, 0.06261830551008529, 0.05878049578164708, 0.05324599189707722, 0.04481817437486742, 0.03504575725410929, 0.02559919303563833, 0.01661334100884644, 0.007056333649824366, -0.0004500594890272624, -0.008390923164261748, -0.013329855567760581, -0.019001044248177792, -0.02252612190197695, -0.027680464067211825, -0.03140965616155429, -0.03716322082077099, -0.039646961135923524, -0.04114002191656652, -0.03792133644169407, -0.032122069403820695, -0.021978097002118765, -0.011560755008722159, -0.001102225025925806, 0.007972342875377885, 0.015457008748190207, 0.02014568329626559, 0.022145158647244347, 0.023507874527752326, 0.024014770163142716, 0.024469182487940624, 0.024054653739972835, 0.02320565445562219, 0.020169356155253743, 0.01572102861164101, 0.009467389277800881, 0.002277379226499058, -0.003785266494445876, -0.007986466101660159, -0.012526639438809708, -0.01810050580632393, -0.022344718909393345, -0.027132020182941335, -0.031241373996618808, -0.032539790151455826, -0.03112276545389999, -0.030155157626830527, -0.026988955462550535, -0.024352720641100997, -0.024474940167899452, -0.024541025371194656, -0.023927337608163946, -0.026096520342222075, -0.027016600284179487, -0.02609200595296515, -0.025510036364596856, -0.025199610861467842, -0.021915321248354797, -0.02012543685728553, -0.019528520934813724, -0.01816945606721653, -0.012042510620600641, -0.007640326491868055, -0.0014178842388045654, 0.0051435317441941904, 0.009719937645263072, 0.009418019826762148, 0.011015085098480837, 0.01006910578368757, 0.015303036291157297, 0.02705767585728066, 0.04445096258164382, 0.06059697202036168, 0.08010065830130933, 0.09320719949180258, 0.09892409055087646, 0.09571756377354289, 0.09096232295711769, 0.07960582260969475, 0.06922688096913324, 0.06311209422005623, 0.06347500303377768, 0.06645785589344445, 0.078023327353128, 0.08851574329950256, 0.09531698519307817, 0.0998110151153476, 0.10172628898107146, 0.09780245226092302, 0.09485799975409136, 0.09530693555952312, 0.09584954266494708, 0.09952894033149862, 0.1047851191988934, 0.10991773409808898, 0.11331429235820856, 0.11622207126489736, 0.11270828893229091, 0.10263626056454188, 0.08676630960032027, 0.06755545363442773, 0.045099189473311874, 0.026390233688498178, 0.017756476219289666, 0.013182759201022324, 0.010742032381724916, 0.009606542678031472, 0.0067069291735103636, -0.003809039545358857, -0.015411184605185221, -0.02599458296875042, -0.03454231344624867, -0.039668588449731916, -0.04000439223181103, -0.03374076198934779, -0.02536091338847352, -0.01146963261046945, 0.0028542931974620835, 0.018753174699781477, 0.03204523298380374, 0.04529792878488164, 0.05137056541444968, 0.05699743618644214, 0.05935448261437046, 0.058630872804674404, 0.05503836550617927, 0.05363133171724654, 0.04880284245429881, 0.04177393334768517, 0.03546415969034179, 0.02731153726628204, 0.01442092693141062, 0.0037700989231494587, -0.005236518239572485, -0.015138318130356387, -0.025826683115106504, -0.03267224291710688, -0.04012832053428179, -0.04617236890821246, -0.0519317523692557, -0.05378090100285323, -0.05856272575703505, -0.06500188218440421, -0.0785179566685537, -0.09235988405499031, -0.10770933749111879, -0.11838823266113156, -0.13176944785588907, -0.13660740693357415, -0.1440653100572045, -0.15125166909559554, -0.16338013048534156, -0.16880054021644955, -0.17426213793695722, -0.17309805997762637, -0.17258568782286984, -0.16994215097559873, -0.16978369888488098, -0.17249049327005145, -0.17667857204961765, -0.17755381298926454, -0.17283524577298218, -0.16329631466708855, -0.1509464459023546, -0.1353231017806456, -0.11991699292712805, -0.10586860449980692, -0.09518736272945304, -0.0863413254175335, -0.08321266022974247, -0.08080313049122169, -0.08201917066725925, -0.0839412254649189, -0.08465353995342222, -0.08137324363568034, -0.07554043291668919, -0.06921884284426728, -0.06458082610032895, -0.06413770909672378, -0.0653369774322024, -0.07180420102132318, -0.07817592780399638, -0.08195395219602056, -0.0773403516009231, -0.07119298330083752, -0.059723350930061925, -0.04527985444930233, -0.03032133695981579, -0.023821874102146853, -0.022142775134089084, -0.030239263234645597, -0.04250440942023899, -0.06094763992163999, -0.07591510613197809, -0.08702664633191838, -0.08727642312228721, -0.08744564944031194, -0.08415405780137734, -0.08173140723520843, -0.0823088624343198, -0.09411512193468943, -0.10688399380781703, -0.12053310207490309, -0.13141246067254841, -0.14125995174628447, -0.13910519425244405, -0.1340870157891708, -0.12215849673317147, -0.11314953297010837, -0.10191390770808313, -0.0953488407121736, -0.08491290137176269, -0.0819846996116042, -0.07809205997223238, -0.07573318803784869, -0.07190797804317285, -0.07340503211918702, -0.06812660489186713, -0.061681450851246045, -0.052846708860519225, -0.04737911352675955, -0.04157254446306464, -0.04311443754138934, -0.04836245100661642, -0.05925858144482062, -0.06913596518676367, -0.08075123107423814, -0.08729900513570299, -0.09332993268198547, -0.09300672863366877, -0.092683524585352, -0.09052694158505617, -0.09407278437478545, -0.09597624182543078, -0.10400347477483593, -0.11672933315210836, -0.130406508580946, -0.14127457185739856, -0.15421949100931784, -0.1703012007223647, -0.18714688488699238, -0.20813315997490528, -0.2314809558511723, -0.2529279431307643, -0.2661331110467301, -0.27185313202482897, -0.2694960855969006, -0.2664217292261575, -0.264313636241083, -0.2680052913589364, -0.2740471719439513, -0.28410790499050764, -0.29096441783124033, -0.2952665907642684, -0.29253485913637134, -0.287791875771248, -0.27889518065519137, -0.26832620753184394, -0.25694260215277864, -0.248843767451881, -0.23969994439942596, -0.23147937123678444, -0.22476632412383485, -0.2193304469647376, -0.20998616048464996, -0.20538168742182944, -0.2041855490053758, -0.20356056592115232, -0.1986451862901482, -0.20167201477577928, -0.1974477034322938, -0.19073830733225497, -0.178448223903935, -0.1717388278038962, -0.15693741796372665, -0.14534205383583607, -0.13003874381458772, -0.11935350874886255, -0.10686296189291006, -0.09739876245753404, -0.08844958403088497, -0.08667099496100841, -0.0874711619476774, -0.08987435179048585, -0.09100219718589737, -0.09707397043911926, -0.0999546443141657, -0.10207682025699753, -0.10361472003995101, -0.11005535969131514, -0.11093025834850165, -0.11316287743188458, -0.11427942750610334, -0.11639977794247978, -0.11079150451750164, -0.10561405061599552, -0.0930618929171736, -0.08077180948885355, -0.06408453738611257, -0.0549910298553342, -0.04801921720233307, -0.05455900467305562, -0.05926176217888836, -0.06917634061485999, -0.07280056608801755, -0.07378807567467091, -0.06332954569187456, -0.051215509542346244, -0.034606962405493914, -0.020268090263458858, -0.007125837602932064, 0.0009095607486407672, 0.007235144116433785, 0.013573848311874937, 0.022790919810852493, 0.034360042283446815, 0.04783179885917154, 0.0620095700565184, 0.07837281476342767, 0.08862540479922532, 0.09724690481713187, 0.1124284763766364, 0.12765123592554065, 0.13605915168816654, 0.14850086624643738, 0.16414680101053178, 0.17301725447129213, 0.18093821638694269, 0.1883160901321147, 0.18915066417624768, 0.17733310935468524, 0.1562418676455874, 0.12215587232794818, 0.08618218924128211, 0.052556906115322016, 0.02497302250932215, 0.0014079913648637268, -0.011823418206398328, -0.026684092289096108, -0.04094736938426744, -0.05711328058256916, -0.06590631349001044, -0.07525738090203381, -0.07496772053483486, -0.07660693592606257, -0.07453820542393254, -0.07499574766775545, -0.06827140523361311, -0.06752285818119047, -0.06107188533874277, -0.05736442051043959, -0.05521879054887614, -0.06470836826320224, -0.06856112432574393, -0.07831859511239855, -0.0802687170718099, -0.08249038311646047, -0.07338957355986052, -0.06790121309017079, -0.052489285434826706, -0.042399621850172646, -0.027517661537659027, -0.02314354457067805, -0.02064216903862045, -0.029817189171852124, -0.03520371293938192, -0.04280195187177035, -0.032030689814334976, -0.004464882461463638, 0.03836170248185557, 0.08041301765240125, 0.12489328325599705, 0.1554555453612379, 0.16873448281761197, 0.16554472788083738, 0.16061709079853126, 0.14880535477879545, 0.13852738646404775, 0.12531674202871568, 0.12270943774536391, 0.11581173691523146, 0.1135958896724074, 0.10907283045827715, 0.11629177104767673, 0.1250182376867682, 0.1412262002508159, 0.15662318157205646, 0.17362318574943647, 0.18331956678710745, 0.1864033929725879, 0.18556386350297463, 0.18599967848075827, 0.19577660999077331, 0.2130069702639929, 0.23613074994013264, 0.26379022859299617, 0.2953056332562576, 0.31170824044611123, 0.3211593190538391, 0.32337420416655394, 0.31723865228154685, 0.2997656784611858, 0.2927892526651646, 0.28539147716040875, 0.2840332756691577, 0.2956811231076407, 0.3232265076070424, 0.34828680734989054, 0.38715649295699817, 0.42775093988198903, 0.4646655080753738, 0.48781187839389906, 0.5109451278847763, 0.5183138740976713, 0.5252630961082869, 0.5274593838739875, 0.545204765155934, 0.5760254505187659, 0.6666831569471438, 0.7606948892048407, 0.8610906457253437, 0.9421805305385614, 1.0, 0.9421805305385614, 0.8610906457253437, 0.7606948892048407, 0.6666831569471438, 0.5760254505187659, 0.545204765155934, 0.5274593838739875, 0.5252630961082869, 0.5183138740976713, 0.5109451278847763, 0.48781187839389906, 0.4646655080753738, 0.42775093988198903, 0.38715649295699817, 0.34828680734989054, 0.3232265076070424, 0.2956811231076407, 0.2840332756691577, 0.28539147716040875, 0.2927892526651646, 0.2997656784611858, 0.31723865228154685, 0.32337420416655394, 0.3211593190538391, 0.31170824044611123, 0.2953056332562576, 0.26379022859299617, 0.23613074994013264, 0.2130069702639929, 0.19577660999077331, 0.18599967848075827, 0.18556386350297463, 0.1864033929725879, 0.18331956678710745, 0.17362318574943647, 0.15662318157205646, 0.1412262002508159, 0.1250182376867682, 0.11629177104767673, 0.10907283045827715, 0.1135958896724074, 0.11581173691523146, 0.12270943774536391, 0.12531674202871568, 0.13852738646404775, 0.14880535477879545, 0.16061709079853126, 0.16554472788083738, 0.16873448281761197, 0.1554555453612379, 0.12489328325599705, 0.08041301765240125, 0.03836170248185557, -0.004464882461463638, -0.032030689814334976, -0.04280195187177035, -0.03520371293938192, -0.029817189171852124, -0.02064216903862045, -0.02314354457067805, -0.027517661537659027, -0.042399621850172646, -0.052489285434826706, -0.06790121309017079, -0.07338957355986052, -0.08249038311646047, -0.0802687170718099, -0.07831859511239855, -0.06856112432574393, -0.06470836826320224, -0.05521879054887614, -0.05736442051043959, -0.06107188533874277, -0.06752285818119047, -0.06827140523361311, -0.07499574766775545, -0.07453820542393254, -0.07660693592606257, -0.07496772053483486, -0.07525738090203381, -0.06590631349001044, -0.05711328058256916, -0.04094736938426744, -0.026684092289096108, -0.011823418206398328, 0.0014079913648637268, 0.02497302250932215, 0.052556906115322016, 0.08618218924128211, 0.12215587232794818, 0.1562418676455874, 0.17733310935468524, 0.18915066417624768, 0.1883160901321147, 0.18093821638694269, 0.17301725447129213, 0.16414680101053178, 0.14850086624643738, 0.13605915168816654, 0.12765123592554065, 0.1124284763766364, 0.09724690481713187, 0.08862540479922532, 0.07837281476342767, 0.0620095700565184, 0.04783179885917154, 0.034360042283446815, 0.022790919810852493, 0.013573848311874937, 0.007235144116433785, 0.0009095607486407672, -0.007125837602932064, -0.020268090263458858, -0.034606962405493914, -0.051215509542346244, -0.06332954569187456, -0.07378807567467091, -0.07280056608801755, -0.06917634061485999, -0.05926176217888836, -0.05455900467305562, -0.04801921720233307, -0.0549910298553342, -0.06408453738611257, -0.08077180948885355, -0.0930618929171736, -0.10561405061599552, -0.11079150451750164, -0.11639977794247978, -0.11427942750610334, -0.11316287743188458, -0.11093025834850165, -0.11005535969131514, -0.10361472003995101, -0.10207682025699753, -0.0999546443141657, -0.09707397043911926, -0.09100219718589737, -0.08987435179048585, -0.0874711619476774, -0.08667099496100841, -0.08844958403088497, -0.09739876245753404, -0.10686296189291006, -0.11935350874886255, -0.13003874381458772, -0.14534205383583607, -0.15693741796372665, -0.1717388278038962, -0.178448223903935, -0.19073830733225497, -0.1974477034322938, -0.20167201477577928, -0.1986451862901482, -0.20356056592115232, -0.2041855490053758, -0.20538168742182944, -0.20998616048464996, -0.2193304469647376, -0.22476632412383485, -0.23147937123678444, -0.23969994439942596, -0.248843767451881, -0.25694260215277864, -0.26832620753184394, -0.27889518065519137, -0.287791875771248, -0.29253485913637134, -0.2952665907642684, -0.29096441783124033, -0.28410790499050764, -0.2740471719439513, -0.2680052913589364, -0.264313636241083, -0.2664217292261575, -0.2694960855969006, -0.27185313202482897, -0.2661331110467301, -0.2529279431307643, -0.2314809558511723, -0.20813315997490528, -0.18714688488699238, -0.1703012007223647, -0.15421949100931784, -0.14127457185739856, -0.130406508580946, -0.11672933315210836, -0.10400347477483593, -0.09597624182543078, -0.09407278437478545, -0.09052694158505617, -0.092683524585352, -0.09300672863366877, -0.09332993268198547, -0.08729900513570299, -0.08075123107423814, -0.06913596518676367, -0.05925858144482062, -0.04836245100661642, -0.04311443754138934, -0.04157254446306464, -0.04737911352675955, -0.052846708860519225, -0.061681450851246045, -0.06812660489186713, -0.07340503211918702, -0.07190797804317285, -0.07573318803784869, -0.07809205997223238, -0.0819846996116042, -0.08491290137176269, -0.0953488407121736, -0.10191390770808313, -0.11314953297010837, -0.12215849673317147, -0.1340870157891708, -0.13910519425244405, -0.14125995174628447, -0.13141246067254841, -0.12053310207490309, -0.10688399380781703, -0.09411512193468943, -0.0823088624343198, -0.08173140723520843, -0.08415405780137734, -0.08744564944031194, -0.08727642312228721, -0.08702664633191838, -0.07591510613197809, -0.06094763992163999, -0.04250440942023899, -0.030239263234645597, -0.022142775134089084, -0.023821874102146853, -0.03032133695981579, -0.04527985444930233, -0.059723350930061925, -0.07119298330083752, -0.0773403516009231, -0.08195395219602056, -0.07817592780399638, -0.07180420102132318, -0.0653369774322024, -0.06413770909672378, -0.06458082610032895, -0.06921884284426728, -0.07554043291668919, -0.08137324363568034, -0.08465353995342222, -0.0839412254649189, -0.08201917066725925, -0.08080313049122169, -0.08321266022974247, -0.0863413254175335, -0.09518736272945304, -0.10586860449980692, -0.11991699292712805, -0.1353231017806456, -0.1509464459023546, -0.16329631466708855, -0.17283524577298218, -0.17755381298926454, -0.17667857204961765, -0.17249049327005145, -0.16978369888488098, -0.16994215097559873, -0.17258568782286984, -0.17309805997762637, -0.17426213793695722, -0.16880054021644955, -0.16338013048534156, -0.15125166909559554, -0.1440653100572045, -0.13660740693357415, -0.13176944785588907, -0.11838823266113156, -0.10770933749111879, -0.09235988405499031, -0.0785179566685537, -0.06500188218440421, -0.05856272575703505, -0.05378090100285323, -0.0519317523692557, -0.04617236890821246, -0.04012832053428179, -0.03267224291710688, -0.025826683115106504, -0.015138318130356387, -0.005236518239572485, 0.0037700989231494587, 0.01442092693141062, 0.02731153726628204, 0.03546415969034179, 0.04177393334768517, 0.04880284245429881, 0.05363133171724654, 0.05503836550617927, 0.058630872804674404, 0.05935448261437046, 0.05699743618644214, 0.05137056541444968, 0.04529792878488164, 0.03204523298380374, 0.018753174699781477, 0.0028542931974620835, -0.01146963261046945, -0.02536091338847352, -0.03374076198934779, -0.04000439223181103, -0.039668588449731916, -0.03454231344624867, -0.02599458296875042, -0.015411184605185221, -0.003809039545358857, 0.0067069291735103636, 0.009606542678031472, 0.010742032381724916, 0.013182759201022324, 0.017756476219289666, 0.026390233688498178, 0.045099189473311874, 0.06755545363442773, 0.08676630960032027, 0.10263626056454188, 0.11270828893229091, 0.11622207126489736, 0.11331429235820856, 0.10991773409808898, 0.1047851191988934, 0.09952894033149862, 0.09584954266494708, 0.09530693555952312, 0.09485799975409136, 0.09780245226092302, 0.10172628898107146, 0.0998110151153476, 0.09531698519307817, 0.08851574329950256, 0.078023327353128, 0.06645785589344445, 0.06347500303377768, 0.06311209422005623, 0.06922688096913324, 0.07960582260969475, 0.09096232295711769, 0.09571756377354289, 0.09892409055087646, 0.09320719949180258, 0.08010065830130933, 0.06059697202036168, 0.04445096258164382, 0.02705767585728066, 0.015303036291157297, 0.01006910578368757, 0.011015085098480837, 0.009418019826762148, 0.009719937645263072, 0.0051435317441941904, -0.0014178842388045654, -0.007640326491868055, -0.012042510620600641, -0.01816945606721653, -0.019528520934813724, -0.02012543685728553, -0.021915321248354797, -0.025199610861467842, -0.025510036364596856, -0.02609200595296515, -0.027016600284179487, -0.026096520342222075, -0.023927337608163946, -0.024541025371194656, -0.024474940167899452, -0.024352720641100997, -0.026988955462550535, -0.030155157626830527, -0.03112276545389999, -0.032539790151455826, -0.031241373996618808, -0.027132020182941335, -0.022344718909393345, -0.01810050580632393, -0.012526639438809708, -0.007986466101660159, -0.003785266494445876, 0.002277379226499058, 0.009467389277800881, 0.01572102861164101, 0.020169356155253743, 0.02320565445562219, 0.024054653739972835, 0.024469182487940624, 0.024014770163142716, 0.023507874527752326, 0.022145158647244347, 0.02014568329626559, 0.015457008748190207, 0.007972342875377885, -0.001102225025925806, -0.011560755008722159, -0.021978097002118765, -0.032122069403820695, -0.03792133644169407, -0.04114002191656652, -0.039646961135923524, -0.03716322082077099, -0.03140965616155429, -0.027680464067211825, -0.02252612190197695, -0.019001044248177792, -0.013329855567760581, -0.008390923164261748, -0.0004500594890272624, 0.007056333649824366, 0.01661334100884644, 0.02559919303563833, 0.03504575725410929, 0.04481817437486742, 0.05324599189707722, 0.05878049578164708, 0.06261830551008529, 0.0637275535584825, 0.061741199035151864, 0.05857499687087188, 0.056727152649843966, 0.055111490031110995, 0.05312878652069113, 0.0488782335219094, 0.04538800396179765, 0.03976660970917137, 0.03483810925051911, 0.030344079328249705, 0.028498060613677174, 0.02757529178891822, 0.02957390376355084, 0.030947051588905383, 0.033666624519263645, 0.03677947999660502, 0.0390365152288288, 0.03998648783899319, 0.04047392275102313, 0.042073775659306444, 0.04317172838651094, 0.04482589011184211, 0.04558486910911133, 0.04656108337457199, 0.04540613294751811, 0.04389726245642545, 0.03910179578070975, 0.034360637922041894, 0.02898272059290328, 0.024582361970626083, 0.019054639017992002, 0.015414603834384803, 0.011707139006081635, 0.007984727843674957, 0.0035431812319980213, -0.0002579548962973546, -0.0037594797776018263, -0.007083131873659212, -0.010094051895077578, -0.014043168140413015, -0.01711022248533462, -0.01948438303628221, -0.019386579658324597, -0.018732567282240306, -0.01551109417080322, -0.012304567393469645, -0.007657944211140158, -0.004548739746709569, -0.001426414454630863, 0.000349485732444141, 0.001975580296023691, 0.0019425176799605125, 0.001229682097571425]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think tuning the parameters of the `find_peaks` function is a decent way to address this issue. By adjusting the `height`(required height of the peaks) and `width` (required width of the peaks) parameters, I was able to detect the peaks that you want.

```
height_adjust=6
width_adjust=8
peak_idx = find_peaks(acf,height=max(acf)/height_adjust,width=width_adjust)[0]
plt.plot(x,acf)
plt.scatter(x[peak_idx],acf[peak_idx],c='r')
```

And the output gives:

[image]